# jquery add an element next to an input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html inputs.

```
<input type='text' class='req-in' name='fname'>
<input type='text' class='req-in' name='lname'>
```

I am trying to do to add somr element next to the input field. I tried `append()` and `prepend()` but it goes wrong.

this is my code:

```
$('.req-in').blur(function() {
        $(this).append('<p>some text here for this field only!</p>');   
    });
```

is this possible? my ideal output would be like this

```
<input type='text' class='req-in' name='fname'><p>some text here for this field only!</p>
<input type='text' class='req-in' name='lname'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.after()` method.

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('.req-in').blur(function() {
    $(this).after('<p>some text here for this field only!</p>');   
});
```

or `.insertAfter()`

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements after the target.

```
$('.req-in').blur(function() {
 $('<p>some text here for this field only!</p>').insertAfter($(this));
});
```

Comment: Drummer beating drummer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Stack HTML</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../repo/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="../repo/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../repo/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<head></head>
<body>

    <input type='text' class='req-in' name='fname'>
    <input type='text' class='req-in' name='lname'>

    <script>
        $(document.body).on('blur', '.req-in' ,function(){
            $(this).after('<p>some text here for this field only!</p>');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```